# Example of a graded ring with respect to any completely additive arithmetic function - is it isomorphic to anything?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic-functions, graded-rings

Let $\varphi : \Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{N}$ be a completely additive arithmetic function, i.e. $\varphi(nm) = \varphi(n) + \varphi(m)$ for all $n, m \in \Bbb{N}$.

For example, $\Omega(n) = $ the total number of prime factors of $n$ including multiplicities.

Let $U \subset \Bbb{Z}^{\Bbb{N}}$ be a subset of integer sequences defined by $U = \{ u \in \Bbb{Z}^{\Bbb{N}} : \sum_{n \geq 1} u_n n = 0, \text{supp}(u) \lt \infty\}$.  That is to say vectors in $U$ represent $\Bbb{Z}$-linear relationships among some finite subset of natural numbers.  $U$ is clearly an abelian group, as adding $0$ to $0$ equals $0$ or another relation among the integers.  The set of linear relationships is in bijection with $U$.

Let $(u + v)_n = u_n + v_n$ be defined componentwise.  However, instead of componentwise multiplication, we define a convolution-type product - this is why $U$ may be isomorphic to something else in arithmetic function theory.

To make an elegant definition of multiplication, we first define the abelian groups $A_i = \{ u \in U : u_n = 0, \ \forall n \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $\varphi(n) \neq i \}$.

Then such subsets of $U$ are indeed abelian groups since the condition $\varphi(n) \neq i \implies u_n = 0$ works strictly with the indices.  So the values of the sequence are free to be any value $u_n \in \Bbb{Z}$.

Also notice that these abelian groups have pairwise intersection $A_i \cap A_j = 0 \in U$ for all $i \neq j$.  This is because of the fact that two distinct inverse images of a function are disjoint, here $\varphi^{-1}(i) \cap \varphi^{-1}(j) = \varnothing$ and so form a partition of $\Bbb{N}$.  In the case of $\varphi = \Omega$, you can write this as $\Bbb{N} = \{1\} \uplus \Bbb{P} \uplus \Bbb{P}^{2} \uplus \dots$ where $\Bbb{P} \subset \Bbb{N}$ is the set of prime numbers and $\Bbb{P}^k = \{ q_1 \cdots q_k : q_j \in \Bbb{P}\}$ is the set of products of $k$ primes.

Now, since we're defining a graded ring structure any two general elements $x, y \in U$ that are nonzero belong to a unique $A_i, A_j$, respectively.

Thus let $x, y \in U$ and $x \in A_i, y \in A_j$.  Then define the convolution product for the ring as:

$$
(xy)_n = \sum_{ab = n \\ \varphi(a) = i \\ \varphi(b) = j} x_a y_b
$$

This is essentially derived from multiplying two linear relations and taking their coefficients:

$$
0 = (\sum_{n \geq 1} x_n n)(\sum_{n \geq 1} y_n n)
$$

For example: multiplying $\sum_{p \text{ prime}} x_p p = 0$ and $\sum_{p, q \text{ prime}} y_p pq = 0$, corresponding to elements $x \in A_1, y \in A_2$, will clearly yield a relation corresponding to an element of $A_3$, however we have to keep careful track of where the coefficients end up and that is the purpose of the above formula.

You can see by looking at the formulas for $+$ and $\cdot$ that the distributive law should hold.  Associativity of $\cdot$ is brought over from associativity in $\Bbb{Z}$, when we multiply two linear relations and take their coefficients.

Thus, we have that for all $i,j \in \Bbb{N} \cup 0$, $A_i A_j \subset A_{i + j}$, each $A_i$ is an abelian group and $A_i \cap A_j = 0$.  That is precisely the definition of a graded ring:

$$
R_{\varphi} = \bigoplus_{n \geq 0 } A_n
$$

Note that $A_0 := \Bbb{Z}$ must be defined.  See arguments in comments of an answer below.  This ensures unitality of the ring.

Thus, let $R_{\varphi}$ be called the **graded ring associated with the completely additive arithmetic function $\varphi$.**

Note that for two completely additive arithmetic functions $\varphi, \psi$, $R_{\varphi}$ need not be isomorphic to $R_{\psi}$ as rings, though their underlying additive abelian groups $U$ are equal.

> My question is, can you see whether $R_{\varphi}$ is isomorphic to some ring already known about?

> My next question is: how would you generalize this, such as replacing the coefficients with $\Bbb{Q}$ or some integral domain, replacing $\Bbb{N}$ with $\Bbb{Z}$ or a group, so that $\varphi$ becomes an additive group character, etc. ?

Note that any such $\varphi : \Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{N} \cup 0$ extends nicely to all of $\Bbb{Z}$ by setting $\varphi(-n) = \varphi(|n|)$ and then it extends nicely to all of $\Bbb{Q}^{\times}$ via $\varphi(x/y) := \varphi(x) - \varphi(y)$ where it becomes an abelian group homomorphism onto $(\Bbb{Z}, +)$.

Comment: I'm not sure if $\sum_{n \geq 0} u_n n = 0$ expresses what you mean it to. It seems to say $(0, -3, 2, 0, \ldots) \in U$ since $-3(2) + 2(3) = 0$ and $(0, -1, 1, 0, \ldots) \notin U$ since $-1(2) + 1(3) \neq 0$.

Comment: @aschepler yes you have that correct.  What is wrong with it?  $U \neq \bigoplus_{n \geq 1} \Bbb{Z}$ for certain.

Comment: Oh, okay. For some reason the following text seemed to be assuming a more general set of linear relations.

Comment: @aschepler where at?  I can correct anything that comes up

Comment: Is $\phi^{-1}(0) = \{1\}$ an assumption which should be stated at the start, or maybe the note about $A_0$ isn't important? The trivial $\phi=0$ is completely additive. The function $\phi(2^a(2b+1))=a$ is completely additive but its support is the even numbers.

Comment: @aschepler thanks for that observation.  You are correct.  We should add that  at the beginning.

Comment: @aschepler So we've lost some generality, but that's okay with me.  I was mostly interested in $\Omega$.

Comment: @reuns the purpose is to study relationships such as $5 - 3 - 2 = 0$ among primes, but of course to get more than an abelian group, we need to consider higher products.  If this is isomorphic to something, please do make an answer explaining in full and you're bound to get lots of upvotes :)  Also, not being unital is not the end of the world for me :)

Comment: @reuns I am new to Dirichlet series & arithmetic functions, so an answer post would be highly regarded by me and other newbies in the community.  I've changed the title to reflect your observation (removed "possibly new").  I'm confident that you are probably correct, as a convolution product is used.

Comment: @reuns Question for you: how can it not be unital if $A_0 \approx \Bbb{Z}$?  Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: @reuns See this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_relation , instead of module generators, we're interested in linear relations among multiplicative generators of a ring (together with their products).  I don't know how to work with "syzygy modules" but perhaps an analogy can be made in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the $U$ condition your ring is that of Dirichlet polynomials with integer coefficients (more generally *formal* Dirichlet series), decomposed (graded by the values taken by $\varphi$) as $$\sum_{n\ge 1} a_n n^{-s}= \sum_j \sum_{n\ge 1,\varphi(n)=j} a_n n^{-s}$$

This ring is $\Bbb{Z}[2^{-s},3^{-s},5^{-s},\ldots]\cong \Bbb{Z}[X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots]$ (for the formal Dirichlet series take the formal series in the $X_j$).

Don't forget that the simplest additive function (and the natural grading on Dirichlet series) is $\log n$.

With the $U$ condition then $1$ is not in your ring and everything is not quite natural (the Dirichlet polynomials whose every graded piece vanish at $-1$..).

Grading by $\Omega(n)$ is somewhat natural in $\zeta(s)=\exp(\sum_{p^k} p^{-sk}/k)$.

Comment: Since $A_0 \simeq \Bbb{Z}$ as an abelian group, define $1 = $ the image of $1 \in \Bbb{Z}$ under this map.  This equals $u = (1, 0, 0, \dots)$ i.e. $u_1 = 1$ and is zero elsewhere.  Then $ux = \sum_{ab = n, \\ \varphi(a) = 0, \\ \varphi(b) = k} u_a x_b$ where $x \in A_k$.  But the only way $\varphi(a) = 0$ is if $a = 1$, so that $b = n$ always and so $ux = x$.  Therefore, the graded ring $R_{\varphi}$ is unital.  $\blacksquare$

Comment: $\sum_n u_n n = 1$

Comment: Then how is $A_0 \approx \Bbb{Z}$.  Something went wrong somewhere :)

Comment: $A_0 = \{0\}$. Maybe if you make $U$ require $\sum_{n \geq 2} u_n n = 0$?

Comment: Wait, you can't have both $A_n \subset U$ and $U = \bigoplus A_n$. If we split $2 \cdot \bar{2} - \bar{4} \in U$ using a basis $\bar{2}$ and $\bar{4}$, those basis elements aren't in $U$.

Comment: @aschepler I think I'm seeing what you mean

Comment: @aschepler I think we just conclude that $\bigoplus_{n \geq 0} A_n \subsetneq U$ is a proper  subgroup of $U$!  And $2 \hat{2} - 1\hat{4} \notin $ the proper subgroup.  And you  have proven properness.  The original goal was linear sums of a prime generators.  So that still works, and not all linear relations in $U$ exist in the ring $R_{\varphi}$.  And things especially change around  when you consider varying arithmetic function.

Comment: I believe we retain unitality we simply define $A_0$ to be the exceptional component that is not of linear relations and then $1 \in A_0$ and $A_0 A_i = A_{0 + i} = A_i$ still gives a graded ring.  Simple...